# is there a way to find out if the user has given permision to notification?

Tags: javascript

After I ask_for_permission the user of the site I would like to know if he gave the permission so I can fire the send() function.

What is the most elegant way to do it ?

Comment: okay, "granted" tells the javascript that the permission has been granted or not, but my question is now how do I tell it to the php? how can I make php to wait for the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `permission` property of the Notification object:

```
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // your code here
```

Comment: Docs for this if you're interested: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission